# How to change the app global primary color in flutter on button press?

Tags: flutter, themes

How to change the app global primary color in flutter on button press to switch between 2 themes with 2 different primary colors?

ex:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final darkColorForLightTheme = 0xff242f60;

  final lightColorForDarkTheme = 0xff03DAC5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var isDark = true;
    var primaryColorHex = (isDark ? lightColorForDarkTheme : darkColorForLightTheme);
    var primaryColor = Color(primaryColorHex);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        primaryColor: primaryColor,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE5E5E5),
        dividerColor: Colors.white54,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: primaryColor),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const Text('Hello World'),
              MaterialButton(
                  color: primaryColor,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isDark = !isDark;
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text('Change app primary color')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code so others can understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's and example how i'm handling the way to change the themes on a whole project.

1.- Create a **themes** class. Here you can add one or more themes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum MyThemeKeys { LIGHT, DARK }

class MyThemes {

  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Color(0xff171d49),),
    textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
      selectionColor: Colors.grey,
      cursorColor: Color(0xff171d49),
      selectionHandleColor: Color(0xff005e91),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    highlightColor: Colors.white,
    floatingActionButtonTheme:
      FloatingActionButtonThemeData (backgroundColor: Colors.blue,focusColor: Colors.blueAccent , splashColor: Colors.lightBlue),
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.white),

  );

  static final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.grey,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    highlightColor: Colors.white,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
    textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(selectionColor: Colors.grey),
  );

  static ThemeData getThemeFromKey(MyThemeKeys themeKey) {
    switch (themeKey) {
      case MyThemeKeys.LIGHT:
        return lightTheme;
      case MyThemeKeys.DARK:
        return darkTheme;
      default:
        return lightTheme;
    }
  }
}
```

2.- Create a **CustomTheme** Class. You will able to change your theme with this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:YourProjectName/themes.dart';

class _CustomTheme extends InheritedWidget {
  final CustomThemeState data;

  _CustomTheme({
    this.data,
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_CustomTheme oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}

class CustomTheme extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final MyThemeKeys initialThemeKey;

  const CustomTheme({
    Key key,
    this.initialThemeKey,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CustomThemeState createState() => new CustomThemeState();

  static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
    _CustomTheme inherited =
     (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_CustomTheme>());
    return inherited.data.theme;
  }

  static CustomThemeState instanceOf(BuildContext context) {
    _CustomTheme inherited =
     (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_CustomTheme>());
    return inherited.data;
  }
}

class CustomThemeState extends State<CustomTheme> {
  ThemeData _theme;

  ThemeData get theme => _theme;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _theme = MyThemes.getThemeFromKey(widget.initialThemeKey);
    super.initState();
  }

  void changeTheme(MyThemeKeys themeKey) {
    setState(() {
      _theme = MyThemes.getThemeFromKey(themeKey);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new _CustomTheme(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

3.- And Finally use it with your code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:YourProjectName/custom_theme.dart';
import 'package:YourProjectName/themes.dart';

void main() async {
 runApp( CustomTheme(
    initialThemeKey: MyThemeKeys.LIGHT,
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: CustomTheme.of(context),
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const Text('Hello World'),
              MaterialButton(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, //your Theme color
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      CustomTheme.instanceOf(context).changeTheme(MyThemeKeys.DARK);
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text("I'm dark now")),
              MaterialButton(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,//your Theme color
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      CustomTheme.instanceOf(context).changeTheme(MyThemeKeys.LIGHT);
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text("I'm light now")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how it should look

[image: This is how it should look]

Answer (score -3):

In this tutorial, we shall learn how to change the background color of Application Bar in your Flutter Application.

To change color of Application Bar in MaterialApp class, you can set the primarySwatch in theme. A quick code snippet to change the app bar color is given below.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).